# Why Lock statement doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, synchronization, locking

```
static List<int> sharedCollection = new List<int>();
static readonly Object obj = new Object();
static void Main(string[] args)`enter code here`
{
  var writeThread = new Thread(() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      lock (obj)
      {
        Write();
      }
    }
  });

  var readThread = new Thread(() =>
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
      lock (obj)
      {
        Read();
      }
    }
  });

  writeThread.Start();
  readThread.Start();

  Console.ReadLine();
}

static void Read()
{
  Console.Write("Current collection state:  ");
  sharedCollection.ForEach((e) => Console.Write($"{e}  "));
  Console.WriteLine();
}

static void Write()
{
  Random generator = new Random();
  var addedValue = generator.Next(1, 20);
  sharedCollection.Add(addedValue);
  Console.WriteLine($"Added value is: {addedValue}");
}
```

I spend a lot of time trying to understand why I receive this:
[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpvXV.jpg)

Could someone explain to me what is wrong with this code?

Mutex works fine but I need to illustrate lock statement too...
I expect that after every adding in 1st thread I obtain a collection state from the 2nd thread. Like this:

```
Added value: 1
Collection state: 1
Added value: 15
Collection state: 1 15
Added value: 4
Collection state: 1 15 4
```

Comment: Add the results as text to the question. Also be precise about the expected results, I see no big problem here. Just replace 10 with something bigger.

Comment: I do not think it has anything to do with lock. lock will only prevent a read and a write from happening at teh same time. Try it without the lock. My best is that those threads are executed sequentially for some reason. One particular issue is that writing to the UI is expensive. You will not notice in normal opeartion. But take a loop that quickly itteartes like Robocopy going over a long list of short files, actually the time to update the console becomes the bottleneck.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - the numbers are random enough.

Comment: FWIW, There is no need to use the primitive `Thread` class these days unless you have a specific *use-case* that requires it. I would suggest focusing your attention and learning curves on *Tasks*, *Task Parallel Library* and  by extension the *Async and Await Pattern*

Comment: Stepan what is wrong with the results? Could you give an example of the results you were expecting to see?

Comment: As others have noted, there's nothing obviously wrong in the output, so it would be premature to explain what's "wrong" in the code. FWIW, a thread can get up to 50ms of CPU time before the OS preempts it and switches to another thread. At the same time, output to the console is buffered, so each call to `WriteLine()` does not necessarily incur the actual data-to-screen I/O cost. 50ms is an _eternity_ for a modern computer; writing 10 lines of text to a buffer takes a tiny fraction of that. So it would be no surprise for one thread to get all its work done before another takes over.

Comment: If you want a good answer, as opposed to some rambling speculation mixed with irrelevant details, you need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "*rambling speculation mixed with irrelevant details*" thats exactly what is written on the sign on my desk

Comment: @TheGeneral: as the indomitable Bugs Bunny would say, "it's a living". :)

Comment: @TheGeneral Hello. Sorry for an unclear explanation. It was at 3 AM :)
I expect that after every adding in 1st thread I obtain a collection state from the 2nd thread. Like this:
Added value: 1
Collection state: 1
Added value: 15
Collection state: 1 15
Added value: 4
Collection state: 1 15 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you expeected those threasd to run somewhat in paralell, but instead they executed sequentially. You expectation is correct.

I do not think it has anything to do with lock, however. lock will only prevent a read and a write from happening at the same time, not produce this behavior. Try it without the lock to verify. (However due to things like the JiT Compiler, CPU cache invalidations and Optimisations, results may still differet if there is a lock, even if it has no direct effect).

My best bet is that the read thread is simply so slow, it does not finish *once* before the write is through all it's itteartions. Writing the UI is expensive, even on something as trivial as the console. Or even especially there. I do a lot of backups of userprofiles using robocopy. And if it hits a lot of very small files, just writing the Console becomes the *actuall programm bottleneck*, ever over *disk access*. And something out-bottlenecking disk acess is not something that happens often.

If you write the UI only once per user triggerd event, you will not notice the cost. But do it from any form of loop - especially one running in another thread - and you will start to notice it. I was particualry informed that a foreach is apparently half as slow at ittearting as a for loop.

I even made a example for this, albeit in a Windows Forms Environment:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UIWriteOverhead
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int[] getNumbers(int upperLimit)
        {
            int[] ReturnValue = new int[upperLimit];

            for (int i = 0; i < ReturnValue.Length; i++)
                ReturnValue[i] = i;

            return ReturnValue;
        }

        void printWithBuffer(int[] Values)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            string buffer = "";

            foreach (int Number in Values)
                buffer += Number.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            textBox1.Text = buffer;
        }

        void printDirectly(int[] Values){
            textBox1.Text = "";

            foreach (int Number in Values)
                textBox1.Text += Number.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        private void btnPrintBuffer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Numbers");
            int[] temp = getNumbers(10000);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing with buffer");
            printWithBuffer(temp);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing done");
        }

        private void btnPrintDirect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Numbers");
            int[] temp = getNumbers(1000);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing directly");
            printDirectly(temp);
            MessageBox.Show("Printing done");
        }
    }
}
```

But even this overhead is pretty unlikey to have a presistent result. At some time the read thread should get the lock first, blocking write. But still, there are too many variables to say for sure. You should propably try a simpler example, with more consistent (and a whole lot less) writework. What about writing "A" and "B" to the console, instead of complex stuff like this?